# How to change the size of a mapView annotation swift

Tags: swift, mkannotation, mkannotationview

Ok so I've searched around for an answer and nothing I've found seems to work. I'm trying to iterate through the map annotations and highlight the target annotation by increasing it's size, increasing the border size and changing the border color. What I'm I doing wrong:

```
for annotation in self.mapView.annotations {

  guard let currentAnnotationID = annotation.subtitle ?? "" else {return}

  if currentAnnotation == targetAnnotationID {
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: targetAnnotationID)
    annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: targetAnnotationID)
    let annotationSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    annotationView!.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: annotationSize)
    annotationView!.layer.borderColor = .red
    annotationView!.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
  }
```

}

Comment: You are creating arbitrary annotationViews and change them. These are not the ones that are used to display. Whatever you do, you have to do it in your `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?...`